# Python proxy http request failing

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

***FIXED IT MYSELF* - Changed list.append(i) to list.append(i.strip())**

I'm trying to do a simple http request using a proxy, which works fine if I hard code the username and password. The moment I try to use the split function to extract this data from a text file, it fails, im not too sure why. I dont get a python error, just an error back from the proxy site that i failed authentication.

The proxy data in my text file looks like this:
blah1.proxies.com:33128:dummyusername!123:password
blah2.proxies.com:33128:dummyusername!456:password

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth
from itertools import cycle

list = []

f = open("C:\proxies\proxies.txt", "rt")

for i in f:

    list.append(i)


proxy_pool = cycle(list)


#Get a proxy from the pool
proxy = next(proxy_pool)


prox = {
    'http': "http://" + i.split(':')[2] + ":" + i.split(':')[3] + "@" + i.split(':')[0] + ":" + i.split(':')[1]
}

ext_ip = requests.get('http://checkip.dyndns.org', proxies=prox)

print (ext_ip.text)
```

Not sure why this fails, but if I hard code the username and password instead of using split command it works. I've tried printing the split command, and it prints the right username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth
from itertools import cycle

list = []

f = open("C:\proxies\proxies.txt", "rt")

for i in f:
    list.append(i)


proxy_pool = cycle(list)


#Get a proxy from the pool
proxy_str = next(proxy_pool)
splitted = proxy_str.split(":")
proxy_url = f"http://{splitted[2]}:{splitted[3]}@{splitted[0]}:{splitted[1]}"

proxy = {'http': proxy_url}

ext_ip = requests.get('http://checkip.dyndns.org', proxies=proxy)

print (ext_ip.text)
```

Comment: sadly doesn't work either, my proxy provider returns "ERROR: Cache Access Denied".

Comment: Sometimes, you just need to define a http_proxy and https_proxy environment variable.

But your issue seems to be on another level now.